# Which verse in Ramayana is Devdutt Patnaik referring here?

Tags: ramayana, identification-request

In this [site](https://devdutt.com/articles/indian-mythology/ramayana/back-to-old-values-of-love.html), Devdutt Patnaik states the following:

> In mythology, it is said that when Rama was returning to Ayodhya from his forest exile, he noticed that the kinnaras, or queer people, were waiting outside the city.

Which verse is he referring to ?

Comment: @Pandya, is saying the truth not allowed on this website ?

Comment: @Pandya, if I asked a question 'Does Indra, who was cursed by Gautama, bring rain to earth?' - will you strike out the 'cursed by Gautama' part by stating that it is delving into the personal life of a person ?

Comment: @ram question has been flagged. I thought that providing or linking details which discuss the character would not be required since question is about finding verse. So, removed the line.

Comment: @Pandya, why is discussing character of person not required, when it is obvious they might have hidden agenda.. by that logic, I can flag several of sv's questions which insert an obvious bias into the question, shall i go ahead and flag all those as opinion-based, or are you willing to edit out the opinion-based parts of his questions ?

Comment: @ram "when it is obvious they might have hidden agenda" this doesn't seem to be the question about. I am not much aware about personality and agenda.